# woocommerce coupon usage count

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to ask woocommerce coupon usage, is it possible to trigger an increase on woocommerce coupon usage once customer checkout? Because as i know it only counted as usage if the status of the order is not pending payment.

I set the coupon Usage limit per user as 1 so it means the customer are only allowed to use the coupon once. But what happened now is customer can still use the coupon more than 1 order only if customer didn't complete the payment (payment method BACS).

So i need a way to make the coupon to be counted as usage once customer made an order no matter the status of the order. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is not required as each time an order is made with an applied coupon by a registered customer (even on "on-hold" orders) the customer usage is registered in the coupon. So coupons usage are registered at least on orders with status like "on-hold", "processing" and "completed"… So everything related is already managed by WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you mark the order "Complete" it should automatically mark the coupon as used. Consider reading this documentation: [Coupon Managemenet](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/coupon-management/)

Comment: Well that is the point, it can be cheated by using BACS because when you ordered by that method the status is not complete. Lets say that customer made 2 order (BACS) with same coupon so both of the order got discount right? so customer will make 2 transfer with total amount that already being discount.

Comment: When using the BACS method you will need click Processing or Complete manually.